# Nikon only allows single photo in auto mode or if flash is used

Tags: flash, autofocus, error, camera

Basically what is happening is if I start my Nikon D5300 in AUTO and take a picture it will only allow me to take that one picture and not allow me to take another picture at all.

The autofocus stops working after the first picture and in order to take a new picture I need to turn off the camera and turn it back on again.

- If the camera is turned on in any of the MASP modes I am able to autofocus and take as many photos as I like and it works completely like it should.
- If the camera is turned on in any of the MASP modes and I take a photo using flash I will be able to take the first photo and then the autofocus stops working and am unable to take another photo until I restart.
- If the camera Is turned on in any of the MASP modes with the lens removed I am able to take as many photos as I like.
- If the camera is turned on in any of the MASP modes with the lens removed and FLASH turned on I am only able to take one photo and it will need to be restarted.

I have tried installing the latest firmware and resetting the settings on the camera to no avail.

I have no idea why this is happening so i’m not really sure what information will be useful to diagnose the problem so hopefully some of you guys will have some ideas.

---

Just a quick update but after taking a flash photo I decided to leave the camera for a few minutes and tried it again and it was able to take a new photo. but still only the one.

Also, I tried it in an auto mode with flash disabled and after a few minutes of taking the first photo I was able to take a second one.

Comment: Is the battery charged?

Comment: Yes, the battery is completely charged. I have two that I've tried.

Comment: Has it always behaved this way, or did it just start? Is it just the autofocus which stops working? (Can you take a second picture with manual focus?)

Comment: You describe experiments with removing the lens. Have you experimented with using a different lens, or do you only have the one?

Comment: Yes, I have tried with at least 3 other lenses and the same thing happens sadly.

Comment: @mattdm it wasn't like this at all when I first got it a couple years ago. also, it doesn't work if I switch to manual focus either after taking the first pic.

Comment: When it doesn't work, what _does_ it do?

Comment: The only thing it does after taking a flash photo or photo in auto is light the grid in the viewfinder red for a few seconds as I press the shutter button.

Comment: Oh, one more thing: this is the built-in flash, right? Does it exhibit this behavior with an external flash?

Comment: With an external flash in auto mode I can get one flash shot off before it locks up like usual BUT if I wait like 10 seconds for the SB-700 to enter standby mode I am able to take another and then will need to wait until standby mode to take another photo.

With an external flash with the camera in manual mode I can take as many flash shots as I like

Answer (score 2):

Your camera is not supposed to exhibit the behavior you are describing. Something is wrong with it.

It sounds like either the flash is overheating or the flash temperature sensor is reporting an excessively high temperature condition even though there is not really such a condition.

You probably need to send it to a service facility that can diagnose and fix the problem. As always, you might also need to weight the potential cost of repair against the value of your used D5300.